# How do I detect iframe resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, resize

Is there a way to detect if content of my iframe has changed?

My workaround is I have a loop which constantly check for the height of the content it effective but not efficient is there another way of doing this?

Comment: how do you mean content changed? A refresh to another url? A form element updated? Not sure the height is going to help you if two pages have equal height. Also if they load a page from another domain you wont be able to access the height of the doc body? Need more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the contents of the iframe has a separate `window` element, you can do this in a script inside of the iframe.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var object = $(this)
  // Use `object.height()` and `object.width()`.
});
```

You could also use `$("#the_iframe")[0].contentWindow.window` (or something like that) instead of `window` to access the `window` object of the iframe from the scope that contains the iframe.

Comment: -1 - Unfortunately this is not correct.  This will only fire when the `<iframe>` width changes and not when the content of the iframe changes.  From what I can tell, the only way to notice that change is sadly through polling :(

Answer (score 1):

```
      setInterval(function() {
                var ifm = document.getElementById("UIMain");
                var h = ifm.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
                ifm.height = h < 400 ? 400 : h;
          }, 800);
```

pure javascript is OK.didn't need jquery.

Answer (score 1):

this solved the problem :

iframe code:

```
<body onload="parent.alertsize(document.body.scrollHeight);">
```

parent page :

```
<script>
function alertsize(pixels){
 pixels+=32;
document.getElementById('myiframe').style.height=pixels+"px";
}
</script>
```